# Join two queries to form one table - in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I generated a query to pull in unique logins by date, and the average duration of each. What I am now trying to do is add a column representing the logins.

The way I'm pulling in the unique logins is by subtracting the maximum and minimum created date (as this is needed to calculate average duration).

I now have a simple query to calculate all logins (not simply unique logins).

Based on my query - how can I add a column so I will have logins, unique logins, average_duration, and the login_date?

**MY QUERY:**

```
SELECT 
COUNT(unique_session_ids) as unique_logins
,AVG(
      CASE WHEN duration > '0' 
      THEN duration 
      END) as average_duration
,login_date                                                    
FROM(
    SELECT a.session_id as unique_session_ids
    ,MAX(a.created)-min(a.created) as duration
    ,MIN(to_char(b.created,'mm-dd')) as login_date   
        FROM base_identity a
            INNER JOIN base_identity b
            ON a.session_id = b.session_id
        WHERE a.source_system_id = 11
        AND a.created >= '2018-12-01'
        GROUP BY a.session_id) x
GROUP BY login_date;
```

**WHAT I WANT TO ADD TO THAT:**

```
SELECT COUNT(session_id) as logins                                                             
FROM base_identity
GROUP BY to_char(created,'mm-dd')
```

So, I essentially just want the logins and unique logins represented together.

Thanks!

Comment: Please add sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You can select from multiple tables with the following syntax

```
SELECT Table1.column_name, Table2.column_name
FROM Table1, Table2
```

In your case, it would look like

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(x.unique_session_ids) as unique_logins
    ,AVG(CASE WHEN x.duration > '0' THEN x.duration END) as average_duration
    ,x.login_date
    ,COUNT(y.session_id)                                  
FROM([...]) x
    , base_identity y
GROUP BY x.login_date;
```

Comment: Thanks, but the second table i'm using is the same table...and the numbers are all skewed when I use your suggestion. Can I use a UNION ALL?

Comment: Wrapping a query in the FROM clause essentially treats it like a table, which is why I suggest that syntax. That both wrapped queries pull from the same table doesn't matter.

What do you mean by the numbers are skewed?

Union does not do what you think it does - it just adds the results of a second query at the bottom of the results of the first query (like adding more rows to a table).

Comment: Gotcha, yeah I essentially just want to add a column to my table instead of additional rows.

But - doesn't the second SELECT clause need to now have session_id in the group by?

When I use the syntax you are suggesting, the results are blatantly wrong. In addition, the new "logins" column is reflecting what the "unique logins" reflects and the #s are way off

Comment: Your second query to me looks like it selects a count of the dates where you have any login - not the number of logins. If you just want to count the number of rows in base_identity, then a simple count(SessionId) works. See my edit for that. Incidentally, for unique logins, could you not use SELECT DISTINCT?

Comment: Yes, but I am calculating the average duration using max - min. This gives me a the distinct logins and I no longer need to use distinct. It is the fact that I am calculating average duration that is making this complicated. At least for me.

Comment: @HyderW sample data and expected output will be help.. You can make it by sample data using https://dbfiddle.uk/ and for result you can use https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ for formatted table..